# Can a broken off LV mirror leg (from root) be used to create a "mirror-image" of the system it came from?

Tags: root, lvm, mirrors

In other words, if I unplug `dev/sde1` -- one of my PV that holds one of the mirrors, can that leg be used to rebuild the system elsewhere?

And what are the required steps to rebuild the system?

[image]

[Asked it here as well](https://serverfault.com/questions/905871/can-a-removed-pv-from-a-lv-mirror-leg-from-root-be-used-to-clone-the-system-it)